# Does Scala support inner class generic

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
var retArr = Array[Array[String]]()
var tmp = Array[String]()
retArr+=tmp
```

But it told me misMatch type, any ideas please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps` trait, you'll see that only following two operators are defined: `:+` and `+:` (append and prepend respectfully).

```
retArr :+= tmp
```

works just fine.

---

Little bit of explanation regarding `+=`.

But when you try to use `+` on array, scala treats it as `scala.Predef.any2stringadd` (concatenate `Any` with `String`).

If you try `retArr + "string"` you'll get expected result:

```
"[[Ljava.lang.String;@37e44608string"
```

But  `retArr += "string"` will not work, as you can't assign `String` back to `Array[Array[String]]`.

Comment: Note that JVM arrays are fixed size, so `:+=` must allocate a new array and copy all the contents of the old one over.